# forest: Draw a roof over multiple children in forest?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, linguistics, trees

I often want to draw schematic trees like the following.

[image]

These don't work with the current `roof` option in `forest` because I often need the `roof` to extend over multiple nodes.

It looks like the current `roof` code draws the roof as an edge path from the child upwards, meaning that the base of the `roof` only ever covers one node:

```
\forestset{
    roof/.style={edge path'={%
        (.parent first)--(!u.children)--(.parent last)--cycle
    }
    },
}
```

Is there some simple/elegant way to get a `roof` to cover multiple nodes?

**Edited to add a MnWE (minimal non-working example)**

Here's the best I can do right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[XP,
  [node1]
    [YP, roof % triangle will be drawn between YP and XP 
      [node2, roof] % triangle will be drawn between node2 and YP
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Ideally it would be nice to have some kind of modifier like `downroof` to draw triangles from a parent down to all the immediate children, like this:

```
\begin{forest}
[XP, downroof % ideally will draw triangle to cover node1 and YP
  [node1]
    [YP, downroof % ideally will draw triangle to cover node2
      [node2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Fair. They seemed linked when I first asked the question; by the time I finished editing the question they didn't so much. I think I may edit to delete the spacing issue.

Comment: You could ask a new question for the spacing issue, but I think it would be best if you could explain what exactly you want a solution to do. The `downroof` question was admirably clear. Of course, sometimes what you want can't be done or someone has a better idea, but, even then, it's helpful as a starting point. In this case, too, it was possible to do exactly what you wanted very straightforwardly (unless I've misunderstood), so that clarity was perfect.

Comment: Nah, I think deleting was best precisely because I *don't* have an idea for a solution. What's wrong with faking space with an `\hbox` like I've been doing? Nothing, and I don't think the default behavior is a bug. It was a poorly asked question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`downroof` draws a roof spanning all of a node's children:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{
  downroof/.style={
    for children={
      if n=1{
        edge path'={
          (.parent first) -- (!u.parent anchor) -- (!ul.parent last) -- cycle
        }
      }{no edge}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [XP, downroof % ideally will draw triangle to cover node1 and YP
    [node1]
    [YP, downroof % ideally will draw triangle to cover node2
      [node2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>downroof</code>]

Comment: I wanted to wait before accepting in case other answers came in, but since this does exactly what I want, I can't imagine there's going to be a better one... Thanks very much!

Comment: @NatalieWeber It is no problem if you want to wait. I hope I didn't say anything to suggest you should accept this! I just thought the questions should be separate. I didn't mean you should accept my answer to this one.